# PHP Posted Values deleting upon refresh

Tags: php

Why am I loosing all the form data whenever I refresh the page? I am posting data from previous page and using `echo $_POST['test'];` it displays everything once and when I refresh the page, nothing gets printed.

I also tried using sessions but sessions are also being overwritten while refreshing the page.

```
<?php 
SESSION_START();
$_SESSION['coupons_count'] = $_POST['points'];
$_SESSION['dateofcoupon'] = $_POST['dateofcoupon'];
$_SESSION['timeofcoupon'] = $_POST['timeofcoupon'];
$_SESSION['points'] = $_POST['points'];
$_SESSION['storename'] = $_POST['storename'];
?>
<h2>Coupon Details</h2>
<form id="form1" method="post">
<span style="width:120px;"><strong>Restaurant:</strong></span> <?php echo $_SESSION['storename']; ?>

<strong>Date:</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['dateofcoupon']; ?>

<strong>Start Time:</strong> <?php echo substr($_SESSION['timeofcoupon'], 0, -10); ?>

<strong>End Time:</strong> <?php echo substr($_SESSION['timeofcoupon'], 8, -2); ?>

<strong>Coupons:</strong> </php echo $_SESSION['points']; ?>
```

Comment: You're overwriting the session variables with the post data. If there's no post data, you're clearing the session variables.

Comment: Because each time you refresh you execute the code in the first part of your script. So each time you assign to each session variable a post value. When the request is not made by the form, those post value will be null. And so you're erasing the session variables in this way. Solution is to move that code to another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario:

1) Add empty values from `$_POST` (No error? Since there is indexes defined yet)

2) You send form data

3) Save `$_POST` variables back to session

4) Refresh of page / removes all `$_POST` variables

5) You assign again empty variables

So basically you have to check `$_POST` variables existence and only save than:

```
if (isset($_POST['points'])) {
    $_SESSION['coupons_count'] = $_POST['points'];
}
// repeat for all variables
```

Comment: Good now +1 for the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

That's the right behavior for a web form. You have a form, you are filling in the values and posting it to itself, then if you will refresh the page, as you are NOT posting any values again so you get noting displayed.

If you want to keep the values persistent across multiple refreshes, then post the form to a separate page [easiest solution];

Like you can make a page formdata.php and post it to formaction.php.
add action tag in your form with action="formaction.php"
and then refresh the action page multiple times and you will see all variables persistent.

Comment: He is saving _POST variables to _SESSION, so on refresh it must stay

Comment: Justinas, you are right that session vars must stay, but he is saving POST vars to session on each refresh. Thats why session vars are overwritten with empty values on subsequent refresh

Comment: As I mentioned in brackets, it is the easiest way to demonstrate quickly what he is going wrong.

Comment: It is NOT an answer. Imagine that when you post values, you insert something to server. So after each refresh browser will ask if you wish to resend data, you click ok, and EVERY time there will be new entry to database.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I ended up using in a weird manner.

```
if($_POST['points'] != null)
{
$_SESSION['coupons_count'] = $_POST['points'];
$_SESSION['dateofcoupon'] = $_POST['dateofcoupon'];
$_SESSION['timeofcoupon'] = $_POST['timeofcoupon'];
$_SESSION['points'] = $_POST['points'];
$_SESSION['storename'] = $_POST['storename'];
}
```

I know, this is not a professional way but I am looking for a quick tip to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are complaining about. If you don't POST the values again when you refresh your page (and your browser should ask you whether it should send the form again), you can't expect the $_POST to have any values in it.

Anyway, this might help you a bit:

```
$pairs = array(
    "coupons_count" => "points",
    "dateofcoupon" => "dateofcoupon",
    "timeofcoupon" => "timeofcoupon",
    "points" => "points",
    "storename" => "storename",
);

foreach ($pairs as $sessionVar => $postVar) {
    if (isset($_POST[$postVar])) $_SESSION[$sessionVar] = $_POST[$postVar];
}
```

Where the session variables will be overwritten **ONLY IF** there are corresponding $_POST values defined.